# How to prevent restoring the application state after process killed?

Tags: android

If Android kills the application, and then user returns to it, it is recreated with the saved state (for example, system opens last visited `Activity`).

How can I prevent this behavior and make the system always open launcher `Activity` after the system is killed?

Comment: Why would a user want this behavior?

Comment: Assume `MainActivity` with button **fetch data**. When user clicks it, app fetches data, puts in singleton, and then opens `DataActivity`.
Now, is on the `DataActivity`, but exits app by pressing home button, and Android kills the process.
When user opens app, system restores `DataActivity` but our singleton is recreated so `DataActivity` is trying to get `null` data from it.

If app was restarted on `MainActivity`, problem does not exists.

Comment: Cache the data on disk.

Comment: We will finally. However I'll take some time to implement and for now we're looking for a quicker workaround.